# Function does not work in if else statement in c

Tags: c, function

I want to write Base transformations.
And i ask to user first base and last base with if - else.
Function herhangibirinedonusum works in main method.
But this function doesn't work in if else statement, can you help me?

i edited my codes. problem is function doesn't work in if-else statement. 
thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int herhangibirinedonusum(long int girilen_sayi, int ilk_taban, int son_taban) 
{
    char taban_rakamlari[16] ={'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
                               '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};

    int son_donusum[64];

    long int donusturulen;
    donusturulen = 0;

    int index;
    index = 0;

    int i;

    while (girilen_sayi != 0) {
        donusturulen += (girilen_sayi % 10) * (int) pow(ilk_taban, i);
        girilen_sayi /= 10;
        i++;
    }

    while (donusturulen != 0) {
        son_donusum[index] = donusturulen % son_taban;
        donusturulen = donusturulen / son_taban;
        ++index;
    }

    --index; 
    printf("\n\nDonusturulmus sayi = ");
    for (; index >= 0; index--){
        printf("%c", taban_rakamlari[son_donusum[index]]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() 
{
    int a, b, c, d, e;
    long int sayi;
    herhangibirinedonusum(110010, 2, 10);

    printf("\nGirilecek sayı tabanını seçiniz:");
    printf("\n1: 2'lik taban");
    scanf("%i", &a);

    if (a == 1) {
        printf("\nLütfen dönüştürülecek tabanı seçiniz:");
        printf("\n1: 8'lik tabana çevir");
        scanf("%i", &b);

        printf("Lütfen sayıyı giriniz:");
        scanf("%ld", &sayi);

        if (b == 1) {
            herhangibirinedonusum(sayi, 2, 8);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nwrong choose");
        }
    }

}
```

Solution: arrays and all variables must be free at the beginning.

```
int herhangibirinedonusum(long int girilen_sayi, int ilk_taban, int son_taban) {
    char taban_rakamlari[16] ={'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
        '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};

    int son_donusum[64];
    int z;
    for (z = 0; z < 64; z++) {
        son_donusum[z] = 0;
    }

    long int donusturulen = 0;
    int index = 0;
    int i = 0;

    //sayi ilk olarak onluk tabana cevrilir.
    while (girilen_sayi != 0) {
        donusturulen += (girilen_sayi % 10) * (int) pow(ilk_taban, i);
        girilen_sayi /= 10;
        i++;
    }

    /* onluk tabandan istenilen tabana donusum yapilan kisim */
    while (donusturulen != 0) {
        son_donusum[index] = donusturulen % son_taban;
        donusturulen = donusturulen / son_taban;
        ++index;
    }

    // onluk tabandan herhangi bir tabana gecis yaparken kalanlardan once bolum
    // sonrasinda da kalanlar sagdan sola dogru yazilir.
    // Bu kisimda da ayni islemi yapiyoruz. Diziye tersten baslayarak
    // yazdiriyoruz.
    --index; /* diziyi tersten yazdirmak icin index sayisini azaltarak */
    printf("\n\nDonusturulmus sayi = ");
    for (; index >= 0; index--) /* diziyi tersten okuyarak yazdirilan kisim */ {
        printf("%c", taban_rakamlari[son_donusum[index]]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 1;

}
```

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't work? Anyway, I bet that's the `\n` problem from the previous `scanf`...

Comment: There are some missing brackets. And where is the `else` case ?

Comment: Fix your formatting and post your full code as this does not compile. See [mcve].  Also, define "doesn't work"

Comment: `herhangibirinedonusum` Why would you name your function that?

Comment: Does *herhangibirinedonusum* really mean "anyway"? Herhangibirinedonusum, there is no `else`in the code you posted.

Comment: In the `herhangibirinedonusum()`, you are computing `pow(ilk_taban, i)`, but the local variable `i` is allocated but not initialized.

Comment: If a is **not** 1, you still check for `b==1` even though b has not been initialized. This could cause an error. You should explicitly initialize `int b=0'` just in case your compiler does not set it for you.

Comment: Final comment - use a debugger

Comment: i edited my code. Can you remove negative points. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said to return any value from function `herhangibirinedonusum`, add `return SOMETHING` (replace SOMETHING with a variable) so that in `int main()` it will know what values follow the if statement and which don't (else: stops the loop that is in `int main()`). Also if you are trying to start a loop in:

```
if (b == 1) {
        herhangibirinedonusum(sayi, 2, 8);
    } "
```

make sure to have a while loop:

```
while(i=1){
   herhangibirinedonusum(sayi, 2, 8)
   if("herhangibirinedonusum==VALUE){ /*REPLACE WITH NEEDED VALUE*/
      continue;
      /*(or do something else)*/
   }
   else{
      break;
      /*(or do something else)*/
   }
}
```

Also when you declared `donusturulen` as a long int it was not necessary to say:

```
long int donustrululen;
donustrululen = 0;
```

You should have used:
`long int donustrululen = 0` because there is no need to say that the variable equals 0 after you declared it (same for index variable) because it makes the code longer (which is not what you should do - try to make the code as short as possible but still keep it working), and also don't name functions that long.

Comment: my question was why function doesn't work in if-else statement. I find solution, but your answer isn't related to question asked. Thanks.